# Is there a typo in this str_replace code? / Am I reading it correctly?

Tags: php, str-replace

Here is the line of code from a PHP file, specifically it is from zstore.php which is a file include as part of the "Zazzle Store Builder" toolset from Zazzle.com

The set of files allows someone like me, who has products for sale on Zazzle and massage that data into a nicer "storefront" which I can set up my way instead of being confined by the CMS structure of Zazzle.com where they understandably want to keep the monkeys (uhmmm... users like myself) from causing too much mayhem.

So... here is the code:

`$keywords = str_replace(" ",",",str_replace(",","",$keywords));`

Two questions:

1. Am I understanding what it does and
2. Is there an extra single or double quote in the string that does not need to be there?

Here is what I think the line of code is saying:

Take the string of characters that the user inputs (dance diva) and assign it to the variable called

`$keywords`

then run the following function on that character string

`= str_replace`

`(" ",","`   <<< look for spaces.  If you find a space, replace it with a comma

`,str_replace(",",""`    *<<< this is the bit I don't understand or which may have a typo*

I THINK that it is saying " if you find commas, leave them alone, but I'm not certain.

`,$keywords));`   <<< then put the edited string of characters backing to the variable called $keywords.

What lead me to look at this was that I was inputting the following:

dance,diva  which is what I THOUGHT the script was wanting from me based on the commented text in the README.txt file:

`// Search terms.  Comma separated keywords you can use to select products for your store`

So..

1. Am I understanding what this line of code is supposed to do?

which, assuming I am correct, and I'm pretty sure that the first half is supposed to work as I've described, now brings me to my second question:

1. Why isn't the second bit working?  Is there a typo?

To review:

dance diva produces results
dance,diva does not

Both, SHOULD work.

Thanks in advance for your help.  I have a lot of HTML experience and computer experience but PHP is new to me.

Comment: Check out the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and you will see exactly where the error in your understanding is...

Comment: I'm happy to say that before posting the question I did check out the documentation for the `str_replace`, unfortunately the explanation went over my head.

Here is what it says: `str_replace — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string`

Combining that with what @Gustek said in his reply, I think I understand but could you guys double check me?  Here are three examples.  

'dance,diva' will turn into 'dancediva
'dance diva' will turn into 'dance,diva'
'dance, diva' will turn into 'dance,diva'

Correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
$keywords = str_replace(" ",",",str_replace(",","",$keywords));
```

You can split into

```
$temp = str_replace(",","",$keywords);
$keywords = str_replace(" ",",",$temp);
```

First it replaces all comas with empty string, it is removes all comas. Then replaces all spaces with comas.

For "dance diva" there are no comas so first does nothing, then it replaces space and result is "dance,diva"

For "dance,diva" it removes coma, you get "dancediva" and there in no space to replace next so it is Your result.